# Updating back the http response body in Salesforce Case object

Tags: http, triggers, salesforce, case, response

Am trying to update back the http response body "key" vale to the case object in salesforce.

Response:

```
{
    "id": "21361",
    "key": "CPT-127",
    "self": "https://demandblue.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/21378"
}
```

Code:

```
public static void createCase(String id,String Description,String Subject, String CaseNumber) {
          Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
       request.setEndpoint('https://TrainingAPAC.jitterbit.cc/v1.1/caseSyncInsert?id='+id+'&Jid='+Subject+'&desc='+Description+'&caseNumber='+CaseNumber);
       request.setMethod('POST');
       request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'); 
         HttpResponse response = http.send(request); 
        System.debug(response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        **String key = response.getBody();**
        
 
  }
```

how can i update back the key value from response to the case object in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is the Salesforce case record ID? Something that starts with `500...`? (It's very bad idea to call your variables like that. `Id` is a type. You're asking for trouble, what you did is like `Account integer = null; // happy debugging suckers`). Call the variable `caseId` or something...

if callout went ok and returned that you can use this to save it back to case:

```
if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
    Case c = new Case(
        Id = caseId,
        Description = response.getBody()
    );
    update c;
}
```

This is not great (will overwrite your description with JSON) but should get you started. You'd need to deserialise this [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm).
Probably something like

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
c.Key__c = m.get('key');
```